# How is Eduardo unaware of the progress on Face Mash?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-social-network

In the movie 'The Social Network', in the scene after Fashmash has been created but the algorithm has not yet been coded, where Eduardo Saverin gets back to the dorm and talks to Mark about how he and Erica broke up, Mark asks him how he already knows and Eduardo responds "it's on your blog".

How is it then that even though Eduardo has been on Mark's blog that he is unaware of the fact that Mark has hacked the facebooks for the other houses on campus, or that he's in the process of creating a website to compare women even though Mark has been blogging about his progress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it's because the breakup was one of the first things Mark blogged about, and it was only later in the night that he blogged about how he was creating Face Mash.

So if Eduardo had only seen his first posts before heading to his dorm he may have been unaware of Mark's hacking later.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script from the movie: ([Source](http://flash.sonypictures.com/video/movies/thesocialnetwork/awards/thesocialnetwork_screenplay.pdf))

> **EDUARDO:**
>   What’s going on?
>
> **MARK (narration):**
>   Perfect timing. Eduardo’s here and he’s going to have the key ingredient.
>
> **EDUARDO:**
>   Mark.
>
> **MARK:**
>   Wardo.
>
> **EDUARDO:**
>   *You and Erica split up?*
>
> **MARK:**
>   *How did you know that?*
>
> **EDUARDO:**
>   *It’s on your blog.*

Emphasised how Eduardo knew about Mark and Erica breaking up.

Here is the narration of Mark's blog for the night:

> **MARK (narration):**
>   I'm a little intoxicated, I'm not gonna lie. So what if it’s not even 10PM and it’s a Tuesday night? The Kirkland facebook is open on my desktop and some of these people have pretty horrendous facebook pics.
>
> Billy Olson’s sitting here and had the idea of putting some of these next to pictures of farm animals and have people vote on who’s hotter.
>
> Yea, it’s on. *I’m not gonna do the farm animals but I like the idea of comparing two people together*. It gives the whole thing a very “Turing” feel since people’s ratings of the pictures will be more implicit than, say, choosing a number to represent each person’s hotness like they do on hotornot.com. The first thing we're going to need is a lot of pictures.
>
> Unfortunately, Harvard doesn’t keep a public centralized facebook so I’m going 
>   to have to get all the images from the individual houses that people are in. *Let the hacking begin*.

Emphasised on what he was "planning" to do, but didn't actually state in his blog (at least in the voice over) that he was in progress of creating the ranking website. Only that he had an idea he liked of "comparing two people together" and that he was hacking the Harvard facebook websites.

Maybe Eduardo read that part, but simply ignored it as Mark seemed to be a person who is outspoken on his emotions.